# IE11 user agent - different on different servers, the same app

Tags: internet-explorer, iis, user-agent

We have a problem with logging into out app on IE11 on production server.
On dev and test server there is no problem at all.
Using fiddler I see that on the production server the user agent in IE11 is set to

```
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko
```

I know, this is the new one added in IE11. But on the dev and test server, the user agent in fiddler looks that

```
User-Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; Trident/7.0; .NET4.0E; .NET4.0C; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.0.30729)
```

Don't know, why it differs?
In the HEAD I have a

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
```

Servers have different versions of IIS, but could it be a problem?
On production there is a 7.5, on test 8.0 and on dev machine a 8.5 version.

If in the IE11 dev tools I change the user agent from default to e.g. IE10, then I can access the app on production server. But now I have a problem to debug, why the new user agent is a problem. I have no access to the production server, so I must test it on test or dev server, but I can't reproduce the problem.

Comment: Do you access your dev and test servers with just a hostname (i.e. without any full stops in the name)?

Answer (score 2):

Check your compatability view settings.  Compatability view settings will set your agent string to MSIE 7.0.

In your IE, Go to Tools -> Compatability View Settings

You probably have intranet sites flagged as compatability or your dev/test servers are in the list box specifically.

Comment: To be a bit more explicit: The option with the checkbox is called "Display intranet sties in Compatibility view"